# Is there a way to look for a specific line of code in web-scraping with bs4

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Im trying to webscrape a page with html lists and unordered lists

(which are nested within lists and unordered lists)

but am unable to webscrape them without the attributes.

[image]

Each `<ul>` tag under a day contains the data for that day. I know how to webscrape nested `<ul>` and `<li>`
tags ,but am unable to so because the lack of attributes. I was wondering if I could take the parsed page and look for the tags under the line containing the day so I could scrape them one at a time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a bit more code,

```
<div class="show-content user_content clearfix enhanced" data-uw-styling-context="true">
  <h1 class="page-title" data-uw-styling-context="true">Unit 3 I Week 3</h1>
  
  
    <div style="background-color: #184366; color: white; padding: 15px;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"><span style="font-size: 30pt;" data-uw-styling-context="true">Unit 3 | Week 3: January 18th-21st</span></h2>
</div>
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true">Essential Questions</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">How does voice relate to the audience and purpose?</span></li>
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">What techniques does the author use to get his/her point across and communicate?</span></li>
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">How can technology be beneficial and/or detrimental to society?</span></li>
</ul>
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true">Objectives</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Analyze the concept of utopia/dystopia as presented in the novel</span></li>
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Create a utopia to represent the ideas of the group and backed up with research</span></li>
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Analyze expository/informational text&nbsp;</span></li>
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Understand rhetorical devices and logical fallacies</span></li>
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Interpret elements of media including television and digital graphics</span></li>
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Create a TV newscast that organizes and presents research with certain purposes and audiences in mind</span></li>
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Collaborate to create a professional product</span></li>
<li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Explain author’s purpose and message within a text</span></li>
</ul>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791824/download" alt="tear drop line 3.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791824" data-api-returntype="File" style="max-width: 676px;" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p>
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Monday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">No School</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<hr data-uw-styling-context="true">
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Tuesday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Read Chapter 4</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations&nbsp;</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Book Study</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<hr data-uw-styling-context="true">
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Wednesday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Subject Complement Notes&nbsp;</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">"There Will Come Soft Rains"&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations and Book Study Ch. 1-4</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<hr data-uw-styling-context="true">
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Thursday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Subject Complement Practice</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">TWCSR</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<hr data-uw-styling-context="true">
<h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Friday</h2>
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true">
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today:
<ul data-uw-styling-context="true">
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Stems Quiz 5 Major Grade</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">TWCSR (Due Monday BOC)</li>
</ul>
</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li>
<li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791824/download" alt="tear drop line 3.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791824" data-api-returntype="File" style="max-width: 676px;" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img style="float: left; max-width: 72px;" src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791827/download" alt="Left Arrow (1).png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791827" data-api-returntype="File" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true"><br data-uw-styling-context="true">&nbsp;<a title="Unit 3 Overview" href="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/111538/pages/unit-3-overview" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/111538/pages/unit-3-overview" data-api-returntype="Page" data-uw-styling-context="true">Unit 3 Homepage</a></p>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true">&nbsp;</p>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true"><a title="Home" href="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/111538/pages/home" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/111538/pages/home" data-api-returntype="Page" data-uw-styling-context="true"><img style="float: left; max-width: 72px;" src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791834/download?wrap=1" alt="Home Black.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791834" data-api-returntype="File" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <br data-uw-styling-context="true">Course Homepage</a></p>
<p data-uw-styling-context="true">&nbsp;</p>
  
</div>
```

And here is a screenshot of the page,

[image]

Comment: Is this from a public webpage?

Comment: No, this is from a school page from behind a login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** *Due to the scarcity of details, the answer can only point in the direction of how you can scrape the information in context - but it does not take into account the path to the website nor an exact preparation of data.*

Approach would be to find all `<h2>` contains "day", its next `<li>` and all its children `<li>`:

```
for day in soup.select('h2:-soup-contains("day")'):
    for item in day.find_next('li').select('li:has(li)'):
        print(item.text)
```

#### Example

```
html = '''<div class="show-content user_content clearfix enhanced" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h1 class="page-title" data-uw-styling-context="true">Unit 3 I Week 3</h1>   <div style="background-color: #184366; color: white; padding: 15px;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"><span style="font-size: 30pt;" data-uw-styling-context="true">Unit 3 | Week 3: January 18th-21st</span></h2> </div> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true">Essential Questions</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">How does voice relate to the audience and purpose?</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">What techniques does the author use to get his/her point across and communicate?</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">How can technology be beneficial and/or detrimental to society?</span></li> </ul> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true">Objectives</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Analyze the concept of utopia/dystopia as presented in the novel</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Create a utopia to represent the ideas of the group and backed up with research</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Analyze expository/informational text&nbsp;</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Understand rhetorical devices and logical fallacies</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Interpret elements of media including television and digital graphics</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Create a TV newscast that organizes and presents research with certain purposes and audiences in mind</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Collaborate to create a professional product</span></li> <li aria-level="1" data-uw-styling-context="true"><span data-uw-styling-context="true">Explain author’s purpose and message within a text</span></li> </ul> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791824/download" alt="tear drop line 3.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791824" data-api-returntype="File" style="max-width: 676px;" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Monday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">No School</li> </ul> </li> </ul> <hr data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Tuesday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Read Chapter 4</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations&nbsp;</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Book Study</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed</li> </ul> </li> </ul> </li> </ul> <hr data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Wednesday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Subject Complement Notes&nbsp;</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">"There Will Come Soft Rains"&nbsp;</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Annotations and Book Study Ch. 1-4</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems&nbsp;</li> </ul> </li> </ul> </li> </ul> <hr data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Thursday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Subject Complement Practice</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">TWCSR</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Study Stems&nbsp;</li> </ul> </li> </ul> </li> </ul> <hr data-uw-styling-context="true"> <h2 data-uw-styling-context="true"> Friday</h2> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li style="list-style-type: none;" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">In Class Today: <ul data-uw-styling-context="true"> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Stems Quiz 5 Major Grade</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">TWCSR (Due Monday BOC)</li> </ul> </li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Due Today:</li> <li data-uw-styling-context="true">Homework for Next Class:</li> </ul> </li> </ul> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791824/download" alt="tear drop line 3.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791824" data-api-returntype="File" style="max-width: 676px;" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><img style="float: left; max-width: 72px;" src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791827/download" alt="Left Arrow (1).png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791827" data-api-returntype="File" data-uw-styling-context="true"></p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><br data-uw-styling-context="true">&nbsp;<a title="Unit 3 Overview" href="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/111538/pages/unit-3-overview" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/111538/pages/unit-3-overview" data-api-returntype="Page" data-uw-styling-context="true">Unit 3 Homepage</a></p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true">&nbsp;</p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true"><a title="Home" href="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/111538/pages/home" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/111538/pages/home" data-api-returntype="Page" data-uw-styling-context="true"><img style="float: left; max-width: 72px;" src="https://fisd.instructure.com/courses/56950/files/4791834/download?wrap=1" alt="Home Black.png" data-api-endpoint="https://fisd.instructure.com/api/v1/courses/56950/files/4791834" data-api-returntype="File" data-uw-styling-context="true"> <br data-uw-styling-context="true">Course Homepage</a></p> <p data-uw-styling-context="true">&nbsp;</p>  </div> '''

soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
data = []
for day in soup.select('h2:-soup-contains("day")'):
    d = {'day':day.text,'items':[]}
    for item in day.find_next('li').select('li:has(li)'):
        d['items'].append({'item':item.text})
    data.append(d)
data
```

#### Output

```
[{'day': ' Monday', 'items': []},
 {'day': ' Tuesday',
  'items': [{'item': 'In Class Today:  Read Chapter 4 Annotations\xa0 Book Study  '},
   {'item': 'Homework for Next Class:  Study Stems Annotations and Book Study 1-4 due BOC Wed  '}]},
 {'day': ' Wednesday',
  'items': [{'item': 'In Class Today:  Subject Complement Notes\xa0 "There Will Come Soft Rains"\xa0  '},
   {'item': 'Due Today:  Annotations and Book Study Ch. 1-4  '},
   {'item': 'Homework for Next Class:  Study Stems\xa0  '}]},
 {'day': ' Thursday',
  'items': [{'item': 'In Class Today:  Subject Complement Practice TWCSR  '},
   {'item': 'Homework for Next Class:  Study Stems\xa0  '}]},
 {'day': ' Friday',
  'items': [{'item': 'In Class Today:  Stems Quiz 5 Major Grade TWCSR (Due Monday BOC)  '}]}]
```

Comment: Thank you, this helps alot. But I was wondering if I could specifically look for the text of those h2 tags, because there are other h2  tags in the code not belonging to the day information. I tried soup.find('h2', text=" Monday") and and with soup.find_all but it doesn't quite work. Again, thank you!

Comment: Without additional details it is hard to give a propper answer, so it would be the best to improve the question. But to give you a hint you can use `soup.select('h2:-soup-contains("day")')` instead of `soup.find_all('h2')` to select more specific. Is there a special container the days life in ?

Comment: This didn't quite work either, it gave no response nor error, there is no special container, and I added a bit more information to the question.

Comment: are your libraries up to date - As alternative use regex.

Comment: Oh god, I feel so dumb, it hadn't logged into the page because I need javascript in order to access the site. I am so sorry.